# View not updated from callback method

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listener

I am fetching data from database. My views are updating only first time when I open the activity. Then when I again open the activity, my views are not updated.(Activity is starting again, hence `onCreate()` is called again & all settings are same). **If I `getText()` after setting the text, I am getting proper values in log but nothing is displayed in view**.

Here is my code snippet:

```
//My Call Back method    
@Override
    public void onRatingDataLoaded(ReviewJsonModel review) {

        int ratingCount = 0, ownRating = 0;
        String averageRating = "0";
        if (review != null) {
            ratingCount = review.review_count;
            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##.00");

            averageRating = format.format(review.rating);
            if (review.ownreviews != null) {

                try {
                    ownRating = Integer.parseInt(review.ownreviews.rating);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                
            }
        } else {
            // do something
        }

        mTotalRatingCount.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.review_count), ratingCount));
        mAverageRating.setText(averageRating);

// Log.v("LoggingReview", mTotalRatingCount.getText().toString().trim);
        myRating.setRating(ownRating);        
    }
```

//Here I am setting listner as well as loading data.

```
public void loadReviewData(RatingDataLoadListener listener, int destinationId) {
        if (mDataLoadListener == null)
            mDataLoadListener = listener;

        new getReviews().execute(destinationId);

    }
```

Next is my asyntask

```
private class getReviews extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ReviewJsonModel> {

        @Override
        protected ReviewJsonModel doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            Cursor appCursor = mRatingApi.getDestinationReview(integers[0]);

            ReviewJsonModel mReviewData = new ReviewJsonModel();
            if (appCursor != null && appCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                appCursor.moveToFirst();
                while (!appCursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    mReviewData = getDocument(appCursor);
                    appCursor.moveToNext();

                }
                appCursor.close();
            }

            return mReviewData;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ReviewJsonModel result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (mDataLoadListener != null)
                mDataLoadListener.onRatingDataLoaded(result);
        }
    }
```

Can't find cause of problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please call mAverageRating.invalidate() after setting value on textview.

Comment: from where you calling getReviews asyncTask ?, also make sure that you are setting listener callback mDataLoadListener to the asyncTask. If possible provide the oncreate method. next question is what is your aim ? do you want that oncreate method shouldn't get called second time ?

Comment: @FalduJaldeep I have already tried that. Not working

Comment: Can you please try with static string? then check your view get updating or not

Comment: @KrishnaSharma updated my code to show calling my asyntask. Everything is working fine when the activity is opening for first time but not working if opened again. I want my activity to run as its running for the first time.

Comment: @FalduJaldeep I have tried to set some static string but that are also not reflecting on the views. Infact if something is set in my xml file then its visible & not the data that is set runtime

Comment: @AshishJohn can you please call your async task in onResume() method

Comment: @AshishJohn what does it mean **not working if opened again** ? Is it like you are launching the same activity from other other activity ? or relaunching the application from app tray ? Also check what the launchMode you have set in manifest file.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma "not working if opened again " means data is not reflecting on views when activity is opened second time(First time its working fine). I am finishing this activity by 'backpressing' and again opening the same. At the time relaunch, views in activity is properly set for the first time and the same problem persists. I am not using any launch mode.

Comment: Thank you, can you please provide the code from where you calling loadReviewData method. hope so mDataLoadListener  you haven't declared as static.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma I am calling "loadReviewData(..)" method from my activity's on create. nothing is declared as static

Comment: @AshishJohn last thing, are you able to see the value in log Log.v("LoggingReview", mTotalRatingCount.getText().toString().trim); ? only issue is that views are not refreshing, is it ?

Comment: @KrishnaSharma yes.. its logging correct data but not reflecting on view

Comment: It's more exciting now, ideally should work fine as first time does work. if possible can you please post the code of activity class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176935/discussion-between-krishna-sharma-and-ashish-john).

Comment: @KrishnaSharma sorry, but I can't post the full code of my activity

Comment: @AshishJohn Remove null check from your mDataLoad listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is callback issue, can you please try below

```
public void loadReviewData(RatingDataLoadListener listener, int destinationId) {
    mDataLoadListener = listener; 
    new getReviews().execute(destinationId); 
}
```